# Offence reported by ImOnline pallet for running nodes

Tags: session, pallet-imonline

I'm playing around with a custom hybrid PoW/PoA block production mechanism based on sp_consensus_pow import queue.

As the PoW results are generated outside of Substrate, a trusted authority node set is maintained in order to provide fallback block production mechanism whenever PoW engine is idle.

The fallback block production is a simple slot round robin timeout-based mechanism.

Aura is not used here.

I run two nodes and see that blocks are produced smoothly by alternate nodes as expected.

Now a problem arises when I try to introduce ImOnline pallet as a part of resiliency mechanism for nodes going offline.

I noticed that ImOnline reports offense for the both running nodes whenever a session ends.

I use 4000 ms block time and 4 block-long sessions.

I played around with ImOnline source code and it looks like that `should_heartbeat` variable in `send_heartbeats` function influences the relevant behavior.

Whenever I force `should_heartbeat` to be always `true` the system behaves as expected and only reports offense when a node is down.

However when `should_heartbeat` is used in its original functionality the heartbeat is often sent when the session is on it's 100% progress and it seems to be too late for the heartbeat to be registered and when the next session starts the offense is reported.

Maybe a 4 block-log session chosen is too short ?
Is there a typical parameter for session length such that heartbeats are sent in time ?